# Accessing a remote server from node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a login page that accesses node.js which in turn shud access another server to provide authentication to my login page!how to i achieve dat? pls do help i am entirely new to node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use http.request

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: I did try the above code but each time i do so i am getting a connection refused error.Is it because of the dynamic ip? PLS do help